# How to use TrafficStats to tag network usage to Google Analytics server

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to use `TrafficStats` to tag the network data usage to Google Analytics server? i.e get the socket which is used to transmit data to GA or the thread where the transmission is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the `tagSocket()` method. You can find some additional information here [Android efficient network access](https://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html)

Comment: But how can I find the pointer to the internal socket which is used by GA?